# Different results when running useragent parsing

Tags: python, parsing

I am using httpagentparser library to dissect user agents. However, I am getting differently sorted results from whatever reason when running the same command on the same input.

```
user_agent_e="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"

python3.5 -c "import httpagentparser; s='$user_agent_e'; print (httpagentparser.detect(s))"
{'browser': {'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '73.0.3683.86'}, 'bot': False, 'platform': {'name': 'Windows', 'version': '10'}, 'os': {'name': 'Windows', 'version': '10'}}
```

```
python3.5 -c "import httpagentparser; s='$user_agent_e'; print (httpagentparser.detect(s))"
{'bot': False, 'os': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}, 'browser': {'version': '73.0.3683.86', 'name': 'Chrome'}, 'platform': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}}

python3.5 -c "import httpagentparser; s='$user_agent_e'; print (httpagentparser.detect(s))"
{'platform': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}, 'bot': False, 'browser': {'version': '73.0.3683.86', 'name': 'Chrome'}, 'os': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}}

python3.5 -c "import httpagentparser; s='$user_agent_e'; print (httpagentparser.detect(s))"
{'browser': {'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '73.0.3683.86'}, 'bot': False, 'os': {'name': 'Windows', 'version': '10'}, 'platform': {'name': 'Windows', 'version': '10'}}

python3.5 -c "import httpagentparser; s='$user_agent_e'; print (httpagentparser.detect(s))"
{'bot': False, 'os': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}, 'browser': {'version': '73.0.3683.86', 'name': 'Chrome'}, 'platform': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}}

python3.5 -c "import httpagentparser; s='$user_agent_e'; print (httpagentparser.detect(s))"
{'platform': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}, 'os': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}, 'bot': False, 'browser': {'version': '73.0.3683.86', 'name': 'Chrome'}}
```

How can I get a predictable result using this one-liner only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that dictionaries do not have a well-defined order. You can use `OrderedDict` (which has an order), on the sorted dictionary you get:

```
python3 -c "from collections import OrderedDict; import httpagentparser; s='$user_agent_e'; print (OrderedDict(sorted(httpagentparser.detect(s).items())))"
```

Or unwrapped:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import httpagentparser; s='$user_agent_e'
print(OrderedDict(sorted(httpagentparser.detect(s).items())))
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all the same.

```
>>> a={'bot': False, 'os': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}, 'browser': {'version': '73.0.3683.86', 'name': 'Chrome'}, 'platform': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}}
>>> b={'platform': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}, 'bot': False, 'browser': {'version': '73.0.3683.86', 'name': 'Chrome'}, 'os': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}}
>>> c={'browser': {'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '73.0.3683.86'}, 'bot': False, 'os': {'name': 'Windows', 'version': '10'}, 'platform': {'name': 'Windows', 'version': '10'}}
>>> d={'bot': False, 'os': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}, 'browser': {'version': '73.0.3683.86', 'name': 'Chrome'}, 'platform': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}}
>>> e={'platform': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}, 'os': {'version': '10', 'name': 'Windows'}, 'bot': False, 'browser': {'version': '73.0.3683.86', 'name': 'Chrome'}}
>>> a==b==c==d==e
True
```

These are dictionaries. Dictionaries are not sorted, so the order in which the key-value pairs are printed is random. Still, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not ordered in Python3 versions below 3.6.

You can use CPython 3.6 or above if you want all dictionaries to preserve insertion order. Otherwise, you can convert the output of httpagentparser to a list:

```
python3.5 -c "import httpagentparser; s='$user_agent_e'; print (list(map(list, httpagentparser.detect(s).items())))"
```

This doesn't require any additional imports.

Answer (score 0):

Order of keys can be different, for instance hash function is based on random. Not sure how it is specially in 3.5, but I would say - that is the reason.

To get what you want I would use `json`, with sorted keys.

```
python3.5 -c "import httpagentparser; import json; s='$user_agent_e'; json.dumps(httpagentparser.detect(s), sort_keys=True)"
```